# Is there a cost associated with static internal IPs on Google Compute?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

If I create a VM instance with an ephemeral internal IP and promote it to static internal IP, is there a cost associated with it? I am curious, as internal IP addresses is one of the items on IAM quotas and there is a limit on number of static IPs per region.

Answer (score 0):

There's no charge for promoting the IP, but you'll be charged if you [don't use it](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#ip_addresses)

Comment: Thanks, but I think that link talks about static external IP address, not internal. I am doing this: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address

Comment: There's no [charges related](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/#networkaddresses) regarding the Internal IPs operations. Even the [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) redirects you to the external IPs usage charges